# Pixel-wise comparison of equally sized images to find the most common colour for every pixel

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, rgb

Suppose I have a picture converted into an array

```
data1= numpy.asarray(source1.png) 
data2= numpy.asarray(source2.png)
data3= numpy.asarray(source3.png)
data4= numpy.asarray(source4.png)
data5= numpy.asarray(source5.png)
```

As I understand if I were to `print(data1)` I would get an array that shows the RGB Value of each pixel at each given position.

Now I would like to compare all arrays `data1, data2, data3, data 4, data5` and find the RGB value of each pixel that occurs the most often and output it as a new Array/ Picture

As an example:
For position X1Y1 and X2Y1the the array would look like this

```
data1= [[0 0 255], [0 1 0]]
data2= [[0 0 255], [0 1 0]]
data3= [[0 0 255], [0 1 0]]
data4= [[0 0 254], [0 1 0]]
data5= [[0 0 254], [0 1 0]]
```

As `[(0,0,255)]` was the most common value for position X1Y1 and X2Y1, the new array would be saved as  `avg= [(0, 0, 255), (0, 1, 0)]`

Is there a function that can do that? Did I understand arrays correctly?

Comment: What is (0,1,0)?

Comment: another color value, forgot it when i was writing about X1Y1 . edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the rgb values to a single base 16 integer and use `np.unique` to find duplicates like this:

```
def rgb_to_base16(rgb):
    return int('0x{0:02X}{1:02X}{2:02X}'.format(*rgb), 16)

def base16_to_rgb(base16):
    return np.array([base16 >> 16, base16 >> 8 & 0xFF, base16 & 0xFF])

def find_most_common(values):
    unique_values, counts = np.unique(values, return_counts=True)
    if len(unique_values) == len(values):
        return [255, 255, 255]
    else:
        return base16_to_rgb(unique_values[np.argmax(counts)])

stacked = np.stack((img_1, img_2, img_3, img_4), axis=2)

hexified = np.apply_along_axis(rgb_to_base16, 
                               axis=-1, 
                               arr=stacked).astype(np.int)

most_common = np.apply_along_axis(lambda values: find_most_common(values), 
                                  axis=-1, 
                                  arr=hexified).astype(np.uint8)
```

**Original answer assuming you want to compare r,g and b values individually:**

You can get the most commonly occuring value with `np.bincount` and `np.argmax`, which you can apply to the last axis of the stacked image array with `np.apply_along_axis`:

```
stacked = np.stack((img_1, img_2, img_3), axis=3)
most_common = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.argmax(np.bincount(x)), axis=-1, arr=stacked).astype(np.uint8)
```

Note that this method will return the lowest value for each r,g and b if none of these appear more than once and that `np.bincount` will only work with non-negative integers.

If you want to return a custom value for each of r, g and b, if none of them repeat, you can define this behavior as a function instead of the lambda expression:

```
def find_most_common(values):
    most_common = np.argmax(np.insert(np.bincount(values), 0, 1))
    if most_common == 0:
        return 125
    else:
        return most_common - 1

most_common = np.apply_along_axis(lambda values: find_most_common(values), axis=-1, arr=stacked).astype(np.uint8)
```

Here we prepend a one to the bin-counts, so that `argmax` will return 0 if none of the other values occur more than once.

Comment: Is there any code that woul let it output a certain color that I define myself?

Comment: Oh, sorry I actually misread value instead of colour. Do you want to compare individual r,g and b values or whole colours as rgb three-tuples?

Comment: I would likt o compare the colors as a whole - so rgb three- tuples

Comment: I updated my answer again with a solution. I left the original answer in case someone finds it useful.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Your code is splendid.
I was just wondering, if you were to have any other values except RGB such as CMYK Values how would you do it? 

I get that you could just convert those values to RGB But could you also do the hexificaton with the CMYK Values ?

Comment: I don't usually work with CMYK, so wouldn't know any particularities, but I can't think of any reasons why you couldn't use them instead of rgb with the above code. You only need to adapt the decimal / hexadecimal conversion:

`'0x{0:02X}{1:02X}{2:02X}{3:02X}'.format(*cmyk)` and
`np.array([base16 >> 24, base16 >> 16 & 0xFF, base16 >> 8 & 0xFF, base16 & 0xFF])`

CMYK values range from 0 to 100 percent which is a smaller range than rgb. Even if we would like to represent more than 255 values each, we could always add a third digit to each of the cmyk, rgb or other values.